# How to tell JPA to use a field of a simple class as the persistence value?

Tags: java, database, jpa, orm, persistence

Consider this class:

```
@Entity
class Bar {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private FooId fooId;
    /* ... */
}
```

Where `Foo` is basically just:

```
class FooId {
    private String id;
    /* ... */
}
```

I (of course) get the error that "Basic attributes can only be of the following types: ...".

Is there a way to tell JPA (or EclipseLink) to treat my `fooId` field in `Bar` as a String?

The reason I'm using some "wrapper" type instead of a plain String is that I want to enforce a bit of type-safety in my APIs.

E. g. `getAllFooWithBaz(FooId fooId, BazId bazId)` instead of `getAllFooWithBaz(String fooId, String bazId)`.

Or is there a better way to achieve that?

Comment: Type safety in APIs is a good thing.  Would the `@IdClass` annotation be what you're looking for (may have to adjust your class), or no?

Comment: FooId isn't really a key in my database ...

Comment: Then what is it?  If it's not part of a key (but stored in the database), look up the `@Embedded` annotation.  If it's in-program only, you should probably flag it `@Transient`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common requirement. Try this:

```
@Entity
class Bar {
    @EmbeddedId
    private FooId fooId;
    /* ... */
}
```

and:

```
@Embeddable
class FooId {
    private String id;
    /* ... */
}
```

#### or (underlying database schema and `FooId` remain the same):

```
@Entity
@IdClass(FooId.class)
class Bar {
    @Id
    private String fooId;
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Mhhh, what's the difference between `@Embedded` and `@EmbeddedId`? What does the second solution do with `@IdClass`? `FooId` isn't really a key in my database ...

Comment: You may choose between `Bar.fooId` being of type `FooId` and `String` - it is up to you. If the `FooId` had multiple properties (compound primary key), you would end up with several fields marked as `@Id` in `Bar`.